# ASP.net SQL Query Problem using Repeater

Tags: asp.net, sql, sql-server-2005, repeater

This is my query I have in a Stored Procedure. I am using a repeater to display the information. The problem is if I search for lets say

> Ename = Jim
>  ELocation = Smith Center
>   ECity = Atlanta

through the query builder, I get the two results that I have that matches that. But when I bind my data source to the repeater and add the parameters, then try to run the query my repeater is empty. The variables are passed in from Textbox Controls. Also if I only pass in one variable, say like title, it works just fine. But when I try to pass in two or more variables I get nothing. Anyone have any ideas on what to do?

```
    @title varchar(150),
    @venue varchar(150),
    @city varchar(100),
    @state varchar(50),
    @country varchar(100),
    @desc varchar(150),
    @date smalldatetime = null
AS

SELECT     EID, EName, EDate, EDEnd, ELocation, ECity, EState, EDesc, EWebsite
FROM         esc
WHERE     (@title IS NULL OR EName LIKE '%' + @title + '%') 
           AND (@venue IS NULL OR ELocation LIKE '%' + @venue + '%')
           AND (@city IS NULL OR ECity LIKE '%' + @city + '%') 
           AND (@state IS NULL OR EState LIKE '%' + @state + '%') 
           AND (@country IS NULL OR ECountry = @country) 
           AND (@desc IS NULL OR EDesc LIKE '%' + @desc + '%') 
           AND (@date IS NULL OR EDate = @date)
```

Condensed Code when button is clicked.:

```
        SqlConnection conn = null;
        try
        {
            conn = new SqlConnection("");
            SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand();
            command.Connection = conn;

            command.CommandText = "seesc";
            command.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

            SqlParameter title = new SqlParameter();
            title.ParameterName = "@title";
            title.SqlDbType = SqlDbType.VarChar;
            title.Direction = ParameterDirection.Input;
            title.Value = TitleTextBox.Text;

            //other parameters declared here

                command.Parameters.Add(title);
                //other parameters added here

                conn.Open();
                SqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();
                if (reader.HasRows)
                {
                    evrep.DataSource = reader;
                    evrep.DataBind();
                }
        }
        catch { }
```

Comment: Some code showing how you're populating the Repeater would be useful.  Are you doing it in Page_Load and not wrapping it in an IsPostBack and then changing the parameters in a button click event for instance?

Comment: @Dave_Stott The data binding doesn't seem to be the problem as I noted above. I can pass one variable in and my repeater works fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is some typo in the query itself.

```
       AND (@city IS NULL OR ECity LIKE '+' + @city + '%') 
       AND (@state IS NULL OR EState LIKE '+' + @state + '%')
```

should be

```
       AND (@city IS NULL OR ECity LIKE '%' + @city + '%') 
       AND (@state IS NULL OR EState LIKE '%' + @state + '%')
```

In addition when

```
       title.Value = TitleTextBox.Text;
```

is used the parameter would not be null but would have value of empty string. That would fail the condition

```
       AND (@country IS NULL OR ECountry = @country)
```

Comment: those first two were just typos, I couldn't copy and paste so I had to manually write the code again and must have accidentally placed the + instead of %. Nevermind the IS NULL then, it still fails to work even if I remove the IS NULL

Comment: IS NULL is fine. The value passed are probably not fine. Can you update the SP to just keep title, venue and city in the where condition and pass all three from the client? The should get you the correct results. If so, the rest of the query should also be made like that. If that doesn't work, run SQL profiler and see exactly what query is being sent to the DB.